# Simple hinge animation in CSS, reposition on remove class

Tags: css, animation

Take a look at my JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hqvakp97/. Im trying to have a hinge animation. It works when you close the hinge but when you open it suddenly reposition the rectangle. 
HTML Code:

```
<div class="box"></div> 
<div class="rectangle"></div>  
<button class="transform-button" onclick="transform()">Transform</button>
```

JS Code:

```
var transform = function() {
    var rectangle = document.getElementsByClassName('rectangle')[0];
    (rectangle.classList.length === 1) ? rectangle.classList.add('active') : rectangle.classList.remove('active');
}
```

CSS Code:

```
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 1;
}
.rectangle {
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: transform 1s ease-in;
}
.active {
    background-color: green;
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `transform-origin: bottom left;` to your `.rectangle` style.
Transition makes changing `transform` property smoothly in `1s` on removing `active` class, but `transform-origin` gets its default value immediately (as it is not set in `.rectangle`).